# Chisel3: False Combinational Loop in Fixed Priority Arbiter

Tags: chisel

The following code implements a n N-bit fixed priority arbiter.

```scala
import chisel3._
import chisel3.util._

class fixedPriorityArbiter(val n_reqs:Int = 4) extends Module {
    val NO_OF_REQS = n_reqs
    val io = IO(new Bundle {
        val req     = Input(UInt(NO_OF_REQS.W))
        val grant   = Output(UInt(NO_OF_REQS.W))
    })
    val higherPriReq   = Wire(UInt(NO_OF_REQS.W))

    higherPriReq := Cat((higherPriReq(NO_OF_REQS-2, 0) | io.req(NO_OF_REQS-2, 0)), UInt(0,1.W))
    io.grant := io.req & ~higherPriReq
}


object main_obj extends App {
  val DUT = () => new fixedPriorityArbiter()
  val margs = Array("--compiler", "verilog")

  chisel3.Driver.execute(args= margs, dut= DUT)
}
```

Inexistent combinatorial loops are reported for this code. The chisel source mirrors a Verilog implementation of the circuit below which doesn't report any combinatorial loops when synthesized in Synopsys Synplify.
[image]

The following compile error is reported by FIRRTL in Eclipse IDE on Windows without any Verilog source being generated by FIRRTL
[image]

Answer (score 3):

FIRRTL does not support subword analysis so by using a UInt here you are creating what appears to be a combinational loop even though it actually isn't. To get around this, you can use aggregate types like Vecs to make it explicit to Firrtl that you are doing work on the individual bits. Here's an equivalent implementation using a Vec:

```scala
class FixedPriorityArbiter(val n_reqs: Int = 4) extends Module {
    val NO_OF_REQS = n_reqs
    val io = IO(new Bundle {
        val req     = Input(UInt(NO_OF_REQS.W))
        val grant   = Output(UInt(NO_OF_REQS.W))
    })
    val higherPriReq   = Wire(Vec(NO_OF_REQS, Bool()))

    // Vec implements scala.collection.Seq so you can use such operations as slice and map
    val upperOr = higherPriReq.slice(0, NO_OF_REQS-1).zip(io.req(NO_OF_REQS-2, 0).toBools)
                                                     .map { case (l, r) => l | r } 
    higherPriReq := false.B +: upperOr
    io.grant := io.req & ~higherPriReq.asUInt
}
```

Comment: The solution by jkoenig produces functionally correct Verilog.

Comment: It's a pity that Chisel can't provide some high-level API to allow bitwise operations on separate bit fields of the same vector to be performed without the compiler flagging it incorrectly as a combinatorial loop but if that's the case then we'll just have to remain conscious of it. The approach taken by jkoenig is certainly a valid workaround for now. Perhaps this example would be of merit in Chisel's documentation?